# Want Windows 7 back after mistakenly installing Ubuntu in C drive

Tags: ubuntu, windows-7-restore

I had Windows 7 and it was slow, so I tried installing Ubuntu on an empty drive, but by mistake I installed it on the C drive. Now I want Windows 7 back. I am not bothered about Ubuntu getting erased nor about my files in the C drive, I just want Windows 7 back. I have files in the other drive that I want to be safe.

I have a Dell laptop with recovery CDs. What should I do?

Comment: When you installed Ubuntu, what did you do in terms of modifying partitions, changing the filesystem, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

If your files are still safe and you can access them from Ubuntu then you didn't repartition your drive and you didn't do any harm, if not then you have to use some restoring tool, try not to write a lot on your harddisk as every write attempt may cause more problems when restoring your files.

For restoring from recovery CDs, it's all about the options provided by your manufacturer and the version of recovery utility you have, some of them use utilities that can restore only system drives and will leave rest of your partitions untouched thus no harm to your files at all, some of them don't provide that option.

But why don't you boot from your ubuntu (or any live USB system), make a copy of your files to an external harddisk and then decide the next step safely and without any worries, doesn't that sound more safe to you?